# Why firebase "Event count" is smaller than "Events in the last 30 minutes"?

Tags: firebase

Firebase "Event count" is smaller than "Events in the last 30 minutes".

This is the screen shot : [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbG4s.png).

What is the cause of this strange phenomenon?